# What will happen when I unpublish my app containing in-app billing?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

So I have uploaded and published an app in Google Play. It's "free", but it has in-app billing. Now I need it gone from the Google Play. So I decide to unpublish it.

What will happen to the people who have purchased in-app purchased items? Will they still be able to play the game using their purchases, or are these immediately revoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users can continue use your application and in-app billing futures. New users will have not possibility to install application.
Your should unregister products for In-App Billing in Google Play for disabling them.